# appending empty nestled lists in python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I am currently trying to add items to nested lists. I am trying to use the nested lists as queues so i need to able to append them independently. Why can I add to the nested list only when it is not empty? is there any way around this other than by checking to see if its empty and manually adding the first element? Code below. For reference, I want the output of picture #2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images as code, instead [edit] your question with the relevant code

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty interesting. So when you are doing this `temp = [[]] * 30`, all element of the nested list has the same id, i.e. they are same thing in the memory. SO when you update one, it updates every one, because they are the same thing.

But when you reassign, it is now a different object, and so when you assign some value there, only that specific one changes.

Demo:

```
>>> temp = [[]] * 30
>>> 
>>> 
>>> temp
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> id(temp[0])
4454715544
>>> id(temp[2])
4454715544
>>> id(temp[0]) == id(temp[2])
True
>>> temp[2] = [3]
>>> id(temp[2])
4454868968
>>> id(temp[0]) == id(temp[2])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in `temp = [[]] * 30`, you are making a list of length 30, whose elements are the *same object* (which happens to be an empty list). When you modify one of them by, say `append()`, the other lists are also modified because they all refer to exactly the same object. In your second case, `temp[2] = 1` (before `append()`) assigns another new object to that position so that it severs the link; now `temp[2]` refers to a different object, so you don't see the behavior anymore.

You can do instead `temp = [[] for i in range(30)]` for example to avoid this; this method creates distinct empty lists at each list comprehension loop, so those elements are not dependent anymore.

Comment: ah i see now. appreciate the insight. works exactly like I was trying to use it

Answer (score 0):

solution i just got. not what i had in mind but it works by making a list and then adding
[image]